# end condition of for i in range(n)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to work with an almost 1:1 Python translation of some existing (very old) C library and found a problem.

The original code was:

```
int i, n;
//...
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (someCondition(i))
        doSomething();
        break;
if (i == n)
    doSomeOtherStuff();
```

It was translated to

```
for i in range(n):
    if someCondition(i):
        doSomething()
        break
if i == n:
    doSomeOtherStuff()
```

The problem is that `i` is equal to `n - 1` after the loop if `someCondtion(i)` is never true.

My solution is

```
found = False
for i in range(n):
    if someCondition(i):
        doSomething()
        found = True
        break
if not found:
    doSomeOtherStuff()
```

Is there a better solution? I would prefer a solution with a minimal code change to still be able to compare the C and the Python implementation. The Python code is only for testing, the C implementation is the production code. So, there are no performance requirements, just readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use more pythonic idioms, like `for..else`:

```
for i in range(n):
    if some_condition(i):
        do_something()
        break
else:
    do_something_else()
```

The `else` is executed if the loop is *not* broken.

Or, even better:

```
if any(map(some_condition, range(n))):
    do_something()
else:
    do_something_else()
```

See: [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any), [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

Answer (score 6):

A Python [`for` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) has an optional `else` suite, which is executed if the items are exhausted, but **not** if you `break` or otherwise exit the loop early. So you could write that code as:

```
for i in range(n):
    if someCondition(i):
        doSomething()
        break
else:
    doSomeOtherStuff()
```